# What is the best way to make a breadcrumb with Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, breadcrumbs

I wonder what a best way to make a breadcrumb with Code Igniter.

1 : Retrieve the strings with URL

example : `$this->uri->segment(2)`

2 : Do you know another way ?

I'd really like to have your opinion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using URL segments is specific to how you have your URL structured - there is not always a 1:1 match.

http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-25372.html?highlight=137949

Comment: Broken link @Dan

Please check this link and update the same .. it it is correct one
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-25372.html?highlight=137949

Answer (score 4):

If you want 100% Match and easy to customize use this one :

https://github.com/nobuti/Codeigniter-breadcrumbs

Breadcrumbs is an small library that helps your manage HTML breadcrumbs with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with buti's Codeigniter-breadcrumbs library, particularly with the "unshift" method and how it uses Codeigniter's "site_url" method instead of giving you the option to push to breadcrumbs using "base_url". You can check out my fork, since buti's repo is no longer being maintained (since 2012): https://github.com/aburd/Codeigniter-breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0):

Please the following tutorial - [click here](https://hackeradda.com/read/breadcrumb-for-codeigniter-3) to generate the breadcrumb in codeigniter.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.