# Codeigniter display location of page

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to make a breadcrumb with Code Igniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494080/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-breadcrumb-with-code-igniter)

I'm trying to create an easy way to display the location of the page a user is on, namely the controller and function. Example:

```
Settings - Profile
```

I'm using the following function in a custom library called `Layout`.

```
function location()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $location = $CI->uri->uri_to_assoc(1); //create array of uri segments

    foreach ($location as $key => $value) 
    {
        $result = anchor($key, ucfirst($key)); //link to main controller
        if ($value) //if in controller function
        {
            $result .= " - "; //separator
        }
        $result .= ucfirst($value);
    } 

    return $result;
}
```

Then in my header file I'm displaying it `echo $this->layout->location();`

**Update:** I also added a if condition to check if controller is `user`, is so display the user's username. Example: `User - Profile` to `John - Profile`

```
if ($key == "user") //display username
{
    $key = $CI->tank_auth->get_username();
}
```

I'm curios if anyone is using a better solution. Please share.

Comment: @Ben thanks! that post didn't appear in my results. The breadcrumb helper seems to be the right solution.